# App which tells me the note I sing/hum?

Tags: gratis, web-apps, osx

I'd like a service (be it website or Mac OSX-compatible application) that can use my computer's built-in microphone to identify the pitch of notes I sing.

For example, were I to sing a G2, it would tell me G2, and it would be able to distinguish between a G2 and a G1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a few web-apps that show you the note. The best being [Guitar Tuner](https://guitar-tuner.appspot.com/):

- it pauses after you sing the note
- it tells you which octave (eg. G2 would be 2nd octave on the bottom)
- it tells you the frequency

[image]

---

Another one is [Pitch Detector](https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/).

It works, but I find it to be quite flickery and it tells you the octaves in cents, which would take another few seconds to calculate, so isn't as easy.

The advantage of this though, is that it is [open source](https://github.com/cwilso/pitchdetect), so you could send pull requests, or fork it you have Javascript experience.

There's a live demo on [the site](https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/), with a whistled 'happy birthday' you can use to see if it works for you:

[image]

---

There's also [Microsoft's Web Audio Tuner](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/testdrive/demos/webaudiotuner/), which is currently a demo, but seems to work fine:

- it gives you the note, octave, cents, and pitch
- allows you to alter the base frequency to tune it

[image]

Comment: None of these worked very well for me.
Guitar Tuner works perfectly on piano, but not well on humming
Pitch Detector was way too erratic to identify a human note
MS's web audio tuner no longer exists. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

It is overkill but you might like to give [Denomo](http://www.denemo.org/) a try. Denomo is a full music notation program that allows you to rapidly enter notation for transcription with [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org/).  However, one mechanism for inputting the notes is to use a microphone so as the computer "hears" the music it transcribes it onto a score that can later be typeset with LilyPond.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform including OS-X
- Providing you can read music & have a quiet place you can see the notes that you sing appearing on the score
- Can also take input from the computer keyboard, a midi keyboard or a number of file formats.
- Wider uses.

Comment: Denemo gives me the error: "Could not start audio input" when I navigate through Input > Audio input

Comment: @theonlygusti - which version are you using? Hopefully 2.0.10 - I can't try it under OS-X as no machine. If you are having issues with 2.0.10 you can try the mailing list or file a bug report http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?group=denemo&func=additem

Answer (score 1):

I tried the other suggestions above but I found this guitar tuner that worked nicely. I was even able to **accurately hum a range of notes**.

https://tuner-online.com/

[image]